# how to diagnose and solve handshake error during api call and curl

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.2, handshake

while trying to consuming an API from a server  we are getting this error

also I tried to do curl to the same and see the following

Received fatal alert: handshake_failuren at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896) ~[na:1.8.0_212]n"}

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

```
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)

    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:
```

Error has been observed at the following site(s):

```
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://example.com/abc [DefaultWebClient]
```

curl -vvv https://example.com

- Rebuilt URL to: https://example.com/
- Trying 0.0.0.0...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to example.com (0.0.0.0) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
- error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: This is unnecessarily unreadable (-;! .. Please repaste the complete copy/paste of your session and use the `{}` tool in the Edit menu for `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. You'll also need to include some `code` so readers can experience this for themselves in the local environment. Please read about [mcve] and read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). Good luck